# Pick input type file value from another form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The problem started while uploading file using ajax but since IE 9 it's not possible.

I'm trying to post a form from a hidden IFRAME, but, the problem is the user can't see the hidden form and the `file` field is selected from another visible form.

While submitting the hidden form I'm not able to get the value for the file selected from the visible form.

How can I get this value?

Comment: so your ultimate goal is to upload a file using ajax, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and I was able to use this:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

It is easy to implement and it does the job you are looking for which is upload files using AJAX. (It should work for IE 9)

Take a look at the link and let me know if you have any questions when implementing it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but here https://github.com/malsup/form/#user-content-file-uploads it says with IE 10 it works

Comment: hmmm there might be some work around for older browsers. Take a look here: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: Worked very fine for me. Thanks a lot